# "Invalid column name" ORDER BY

Tags: sql

When i run my query i receive the following message:

```
Invalid column name 'column1'
```

query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * From (
(select Top 2 convert(datetime,column1,101) AS TEST from table1 ORDER BY column1 DESC) X                   
ORDER BY column1)
```

Comment: There's no column1 there...

Comment: This is not MySQL, probably SQL Server/Sybase

Comment: You need to select column1 in the sub-query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 TEST 
From (
       SELECT Top 2 
            convert(datetime,column1,101) AS TEST,
            column1         // <- include column1
       FROM  table1 
       ORDER BY column1 DESC
     ) X                   
ORDER BY column1 ASC
```

Comment: change `SELECT *` for  `SELECT TOP 1 TEST `

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the simplest way is to move the conversion out of the subquery:

```
SELECT TOP 1 convert(datetime, column1, 101) as test
From (select Top 2 t.*
      from table1 
      order by column1 desc
     ) X                   
ORDER BY column1;
```

Or, if your database supports it, use the ANSI standard `FETCH`/`OFFSET`:

```
select convert(datetime, column1, 101) as test
from table1
order by column1 desc
offset 1 row
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Answer (score -1):

change 'convert(datetime,column1,101) AS TEST' to 'convert(datetime,column1,101) AS column1'